# Is my neural network working?

Tags: backpropagation, definitions

I recently just finished programming a neural network in c#, and it seems like it's working. My question is if I'm doing it right. It's a very confusing process so I will explain.

Basically every neuron in the network has a bias (except the first layer) and fully connected weights to the next. every neuron also has a `double[] desiredBias` which holds all the desired changes to the neuron for every iteration in a given mini batch. The same thing for the weights. So I start from the last layer, and from there I calculate the "sensitivity" you might say between the cost of a given neuron on that last layer and the bias, and i take note of it (put it into changes). Then for every weight connected to the layer behind, I also calculate the sensitivity for that one. And I keep doing that until I get to the second to first layer. And to take note of the `desiredChanges` for neurons not in the last layer, I use this array called "`changes`". For the first layer it's basically just a list of all the derivatives of the activations (z) with respect to the actual activations (sigmoid(z)) respectively. After I shift to the layer behind, and behind, every time I do that, I create a new changes array, which is the size of the layer behind, and for each item in the previous changes array, I take the sum of all of them multiplied by the partial derivative of that same z-activation with respect to the previous layer's z activation. I do this for every neuron in the previous layer.

after all of that I end up with for every neuron a list of desired changes to it's bias, and a list of lists which contain desired changes to the weights of each neuron. Then for each neuron (except for the first of course) I average together all of the biases and SUBTRACT it from the neuron's bias. I do the same thing for the weights.

Is this the correct process to go through for exactly one batch of training data?

here's my code:

```
using System;

namespace NeuralNetwork {
    
    public class Functions {
        
        // Activation Functions
        
        public static double sigmoid(double x) {
            return 1 / (1 + Math.Pow(Math.E, -x));
        }
        public static double ReLU(double x) {
            return Math.Max(0, x);
        }
        public static double Tanh(double x) {
            return Math.Tanh(x);
        }
        public static double Linear(double x) {
            return x;
        }
        
        // Derivatives
        
        public static double sigmoidDerivative(double x) {
            return sigmoid(x) * (1 - sigmoid(x));
        }
        public static double ReLUDerivative(double x) {
            return (x > 0) ? 1 : 0;
        }
        public static double TanhDerivative(double x) {
            return 1 - (Math.Pow(Tanh(x) * Tanh(x), 2));
        }
        public static double LinearDerivative(double x) {
            return 1;
        }
        
        public enum ActFunction {
            Sigmoid,
            ReLU,
            Tanh,
            Linear
        }
        
        // Loss Functions
        
        public static double MSE(double[] outputs, double[] desired) {
            double sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < outputs.Length; i++) {
                sum += Math.Pow((outputs[i] - desired[i]), 2);
            }
            return sum / outputs.Length;
        }
        
        // Derivatives
        
        public static double[] MSEDerivative(double[] outputs, double[] desired) {
            double[] derivatives = new double[outputs.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < outputs.Length; i++) {
                derivatives[i] = 2 * (outputs[i] - desired[i]);
            }
            return derivatives;
        }
        
        public enum LossFunction {
            MSE
        }
        
    }
    
    public class Neuron {
    
        public double activation = 0;
        public Functions.ActFunction activationFunction = Functions.ActFunction.Linear;
        
        public double bias;
        public double[] weights = new double[] {};
        public int x;
        public int y;
        public Neuron[][] network;
        
        public double[] desiredBias;
        public double[][] desiredWeights;
        
        public void fire() {
            for (int i = 0; i < network[x + 1].Length; i++) {
                Neuron next = network[x + 1][i];
                next.activation += activation * weights[i];
            }
        }
    
        public void activate() {
            double n_activation = activation + bias;
            
            switch(activationFunction) {
                case Functions.ActFunction.Sigmoid:
                    activation = Functions.sigmoid(n_activation);
                    break;
                case Functions.ActFunction.ReLU:
                    activation = Functions.ReLU(n_activation);
                    break;
                case Functions.ActFunction.Tanh:
                    activation = Functions.Tanh(n_activation);
                    break;
                case Functions.ActFunction.Linear:
                    activation = Functions.Linear(n_activation);
                    break;
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    public class Network {
    
        public Neuron[][] network;
        public double learningRate;
        public int iterations;
        public Functions.LossFunction lossFunction;
        public int trainingLength;
    
        public Network(int[] size, double _learningRate, int _iterations, int _trainingLength, Functions.LossFunction _lossFunction) {
            learningRate = _learningRate;
            iterations = _iterations;
            trainingLength = _trainingLength;
            lossFunction = _lossFunction;
            network = new Neuron[size.Length][];
            for (int i = 0; i < size.Length; i++) {
                network[i] = new Neuron[size[i]];
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < size.Length; i++) { 
                for (int j = 0; j < size[i]; j++) { 
                    network[i][j] = new Neuron();
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < network.Length - 1; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < network[i].Length; j++) { 
                    Neuron neuron = network[i][j];
                    neuron.weights = new double[network[i + 1].Length];
                    neuron.desiredWeights = new double[neuron.weights.Length][]; // i would have put iterations right here but the compiler thinks otherwise
                    for (int k = 0; k < neuron.desiredWeights.Length; k++) {
                        neuron.desiredWeights[k] = new double[trainingLength/iterations];
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = 1; i < network.Length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < network[i].Length; j++) { 
                    Neuron neuron = network[i][j];
                    neuron.desiredBias = new double[trainingLength/iterations];
                }
            }
        }
    
        public void init() {
            Random rand = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < network.Length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < network[i].Length; j++) {
                    Neuron neuron = network[i][j];
                    neuron.x = i;
                    neuron.y = j;
                    neuron.network = network;
                    
                    if (i != 0) {
                        neuron.bias = (rand.NextDouble() * 2) - 1;
                    }
                    
                    if (i != network.Length - 1) {
                        for (int k = 0; k < network[neuron.x + 1].Length; k++) {
                            neuron.weights[k] = (rand.NextDouble() * 20) - 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        public void info() {
            Console.WriteLine("Here are the statistics for the network:\n");
            
            for (int i = 0; i < network.Length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < network[i].Length; j++) {
                    Neuron neuron = network[i][j];
                    Console.WriteLine("Neuron " + j + " of layer " + i);
                    //Console.WriteLine("Activation: " + neuron.activation);
                    Console.WriteLine("Bias: " + neuron.bias);
                    Console.WriteLine("X and Y: " + neuron.x + ", " + neuron.y);
                    string weights = "Weights: ";
                    foreach (double weight in neuron.weights) {
                        weights += weight + " ";
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(weights);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
            
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        
        public double[] run(double[] inputs) {
            // initialize inputs
            for (int i = 0; i < network[0].Length; i++) {
                network[0][i].activation = inputs[i];
            }
            
            for (int i = 0; i < network.Length - 1; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < network[i].Length; j++) {
                    Neuron neuron = network[i][j];
                    neuron.fire();
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < network[i + 1].Length; j++) {
                    Neuron neuron = network[i + 1][j];
                    neuron.activate();
                }
            }
            
            // get outputs
            
            Neuron[] outputs = network[network.Length - 1];
            double[] activations = new double[outputs.Length];
            
            for (int i = 0; i < outputs.Length; i++) {
                activations[i] = outputs[i].activation;
            }
            
            return activations;
        }
        
        public double iteration() {
            Random rand = new Random();
            
            int iterationLength = trainingLength/iterations;
            double[] costs = new double[iterationLength];
            
            // training
            
            for (int iter = 0; iter < iterationLength; iter++) {
                double[] inputs = { (rand.NextDouble() ), ( rand.NextDouble() )};
                double[] answers = { inputs[0] + inputs[1] };
                double[] outputs = run(inputs);
                
                for (int i = 0; i < network.Length; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < network[i].Length; j++) {
                        Neuron neuron = network[i][j];
                        neuron.desiredBias = new double[iterationLength];
                        if (i == network.Length - 1) continue;
                        neuron.desiredWeights = new double[network[i + 1].Length][];
                        for (int k = 0; k < neuron.desiredWeights.Length; k++) {
                            neuron.desiredWeights[k] = new double[iterationLength];
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                double cost = 0;
                switch(lossFunction) {
                    case Functions.LossFunction.MSE:
                        cost = Functions.MSE(outputs, answers);
                        break;
                }
                
                costs[iter] = cost;
                
                double[] changes = new double[network[network.Length - 1].Length];
                switch(lossFunction) {
                    case Functions.LossFunction.MSE:
                        changes = Functions.MSEDerivative(outputs, answers); 
                        break;
                }
                
                for (int i = 0; i < changes.Length; i++) {
                    Neuron neuron = network[network.Length - 1][i];
                    double act = neuron.activation;
                    switch(neuron.activationFunction) {
                        case Functions.ActFunction.Sigmoid:
                            changes[i] *= Functions.sigmoidDerivative(Math.Log(act / (1 - act)));
                            break;
                        case Functions.ActFunction.Linear:
                            changes[i] *= Functions.LinearDerivative(act);
                            break;
                    }
                }
                
                for (int i = network.Length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < network[i].Length; j++) {
                        Neuron bNeuron = network[i][j];
                        bNeuron.desiredBias[iter] += changes[j]; // bias partial derivative is always one
                        for (int k = 0; k < network[i - 1].Length; k++) {
                            Neuron aNeuron = network[i - 1][k];
                            aNeuron.desiredWeights[bNeuron.y][iter] += aNeuron.weights[bNeuron.y] * changes[j]; // chain rule
                        }
                    }
                    
                    double[] holderChanges = changes;
                    changes = new double[network[i - 1].Length];
                    for (int j = 0; j < changes.Length; j++) {
                        for (int k = 0; k < holderChanges.Length; k++) {
                            Neuron aNeuron = network[i - 1][j];
                            Neuron bNeuron = network[i][k];
                            switch(aNeuron.activationFunction) {
                                case Functions.ActFunction.Sigmoid:
                                    double activation = aNeuron.activation;
                                    changes[j] += Functions.sigmoidDerivative(Math.Log(activation / 1 - activation)) * aNeuron.weights[bNeuron.y] * holderChanges[k];
                                    break;
                                case Functions.ActFunction.Linear:
                                    activation = aNeuron.activation;
                                    changes[j] += Functions.LinearDerivative(activation) * aNeuron.weights[bNeuron.y] * holderChanges[k];
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                // reset activations 
            
                for (int i = 0; i < network.Length; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < network[i].Length; j++) {
                        Neuron neuron = network[i][j];
                        neuron.activation = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            
            // after everything we now actually add the desired changes
            
            // the weights
            for (int i = 0; i < network.Length - 1; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < network[i].Length; j++) {
                    Neuron neuron = network[i][j];
                    for (int k = 0; k < neuron.desiredWeights.Length; k++) {
                        double weightSum = 0;
                        foreach (double weight in neuron.desiredWeights[k]) {
                            weightSum += weight;
                        }
                        weightSum /= iterationLength;
                        neuron.weights[k] -= learningRate * weightSum;
                    }
                }
            }
            
            // the biases
            for (int i = 1; i < network.Length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < network[i].Length; j++) {
                    Neuron neuron = network[i][j];
                    double biasSum = 0;
                    foreach (double bias in neuron.desiredBias) {
                        biasSum += bias;
                    }
                    biasSum /= iterationLength;
                    neuron.bias -= learningRate * biasSum;
                }
            }
            
            double netcost = 0;
            foreach (double cost in costs) {
                netcost += cost;
            }
            
            return netcost/costs.Length;
        }
        
        public void epoch(bool showInfo) {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting training...\n");
            
            for (int iter = 0; iter < iterations; iter++) {
                double cost = iteration();
                if (showInfo) info();
                
                Console.WriteLine("Cost for iteration " + iter + ": " + cost + "\n");
                
                // reset desired
                
                for (int k = 0; k < network.Length - 1; k++) {
                    for (int l = 0; l < network[k].Length; l++) {
                        Neuron neuron = network[k][l];
                        for (int i = 0; i < neuron.desiredWeights.Length; i++) {
                            for (int j = 0; j < neuron.desiredWeights[i].Length; j++) {
                                neuron.desiredWeights[i][j] = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                for (int k = 1; k < network.Length; k++) {
                    for (int l = 0; l < network[k].Length; l++) {
                        Neuron neuron = network[k][l];
                        for (int i = 0; i < neuron.desiredBias.Length; i++) {
                            neuron.desiredBias[i] = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            Console.WriteLine("Training finished!\n");
        }
        
        public void prompt() {
            while(true) {
                
                Console.WriteLine("What would you like to do?");
                Console.WriteLine("Train, info, run or end?");
                
                string answer = Console.ReadLine();
                
                if (answer.ToLower() == "end") {
                    Console.WriteLine("...");
                    break;
                }
                
                switch(answer.ToLower()) {
                    case "info":
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        info();
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        break;
                    case "run":
                        double[] runanswer = new double[network[0].Length];
                        while (true) {
                            try {
                                for (int i = 0; i < network[0].Length; i++) {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Enter input " + i);
                                    runanswer[i] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                                }
                                
                                Console.WriteLine("Running...\n");
                                
                                double[] outputs = run(runanswer);
                                string _string = "";
                                
                                foreach (double output in outputs) {
                                    _string += output;
                                }
                                
                                Console.WriteLine("Here were the outputs:");
                                Console.WriteLine(_string + "\n");
                                break;
                            } catch (FormatException exception) {
                                Console.WriteLine("Only numbers!");
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case "train":
                        int trainanswer = 0;
                        int trainanswer2 = 0;
                        double trainanswer3 = 0;
                        while (true) {
                            try {
                                Console.WriteLine("Enter epoch length:");
                                trainanswer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                                trainingLength = trainanswer;
                                
                                Console.WriteLine("\nEnter batch size:");
                                trainanswer2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                                iterations = trainanswer2;
                                
                                Console.WriteLine("\nEnter learning rate:");
                                trainanswer3 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                                learningRate = trainanswer3;
                                
                                for (int i = 0; i < trainanswer2; i++) {
                                    double cost = iteration();
                                    Console.WriteLine("The cost was: " + cost + "\n");
                                }
                                break;
                            } catch (FormatException exception) {
                                Console.WriteLine("Only numbers!");
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid command!\n");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    
    }
    
    public class Run {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            
            Network brain = new Network(new int[] { 2, 1 }, .01, 50, 50, Functions.LossFunction.MSE);
            brain.init();
            
            int i = 7;
            while (i > 0) {
                brain.epoch(false);
                i--;
            }
            
            brain.prompt();
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

*** to clarify if you don't understand my question, I'm just asking if i'm implementing backpropagation correctly

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I highly doubt anyone is going to check your code or exact implementation as that is a very time consuming process. Luckily for you though, you don't need someone to check, you can check it yourself with **gradient checking**! The basic process is to manually calculate the exact gradient for every single parameter for an input by varying every parameter one at a time, then seeing how each changes your output. With a proper implementation of backpropagation, the gradients will match.

[Here's another question describing this process on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47506918/9546874)

Note though that with ReLU the function is undefined at 0, and you will quickly see how this is a problem when you start doing grad checking. The gradients wont match if you try and check a parameter using the output of a ReLU function when the input to said ReLU is 0. I did some research on this a while ago when I had this problem, and I believe the consensus was to just ignore it

Comment: You're right. I don't know why I thought anyone would. I will try this method, thank you.